# hibernate - create a primary key of string type for mysql connection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to create a column 'Barcode' which is to be the primary key and of type string.

this is what i am doing :

```
// for table-one
    @Id
    @Column(name = "BARCODE", nullable=false)
    private String barcode;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "BARCODE")
    private List<Doc_Mvmnt> doc_mvmnt = new ArrayList<>();
```

and in another where table-one will have one to many mapping

```
//for table-two
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BARCODE", nullable=false)
    public String barcode;
```

I am recieving the exception : 
`Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on database.Doc_Mvmnt.barcode references an unknown entity: java.lang.String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your table-one object is in fact your Barcode object and it has an @Entity annotation on it.

Then, your table-two object is your Doc_Mvmnt object.  The problem is that you are establishing a @ManyToOne relationship against a String object (which is not an entity, per your error).  Instead, change 'String' to 'Barcode'.  I also took the liberty to make it a private member, even though public should work too.

It should look like this:

```
//for table-two
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "BARCODE", nullable=false)
private Barcode barcode;
```

Comment: no , my table1 is doc_master which has 'barcode' column. I was trying to join the two tables using barcode as the key. I want the key to be of type string, so that in the table it becomes varchar(to make it hold both alphabets and numbers)

Comment: The error you are getting is because you are referencing an "unknown entity".  A String is a *not* a Hibernate entity.  DocMaster object has the barcode as it's ID (aka, primary key).  DocMaster *is* an entity.  Hence, what you need to do is, in table-two, replace 'public String barcode' with 'public DocMaster docMaster'.  That will resolve your error.